# Scala traits exposing protected members?

Tags: scala

Given a class like:

```
class MyClass {
    protected object MyObj { ... }
}
```

is it possible to write a trait that will permit exposing `MyObj`. E.g. with inheritance I could do the following:

```
class TestMyClass extends MyClass {
    val getMyObj = MyObj
}
```

but I want to do this via a trait, something like the following which doesn't typecheck:

```
trait ExposeMyObj {
    val getMyObj = MyObj        // super.MyObj/this.MyObj don't work 
}
```

and use it like:

```
class TestMyClass extends ExposeMyObj
```

Is it possible to reproduce the functionality in `TestMyClass` into a trait to expose the protected object, and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that your trait will always be mixed in to an instance of `MyClass` (or a subclass), you can enforce the expectation with a self-type, and then access the object:

```
trait ExposeMyObj {
    self: MyClass =>

    val getMyObj = MyObj
}
```

**Edit**: an example of using this trait:

```
class TestMyClass extends MyClass with ExposeMyObj

val test = new TestMyClass
test.getMyObj // accesses MyObj defined in MyClass.
```

**Edit 2**: attempting to address @jbrown's comment (re: testing queries within repos) - I would look at doing something like the following - first, in each repo's file, add a trait for each repo holding the queries for that repo:

```
trait UserQueries { // you could look at making this protected, if you like

  protected def query1(param: String) = List(param) // very silly implementation, but hopefully enough to make the point
  ... // other queries
}

class UserRepo extends UserQueries // Has (internal) access to those queries
```

Then in the test class file for a given repo:

```
class UserQueriesTester extends UserQueries with ScalaTest { // or whatever test framework you are using

  // (public) tests to run - eg:
  def testQuery1 = query1("test") should be (List("test"))

}
```

Comment: I don't, but I could make them all extend a particular trait. But how can I declare `protected object MyObj` in the trait and then have subclasses override it? Do I need to make `MyObj` a class instead? I'd rather not...

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you misunderstand me - you still have the class `MyClass` defined as before (with a protected object `MyObj`). Then any subclass of `MyClass` that wants to expose the object can extend the above trait (as well as `MyClass`). Your query about declaring the protected object in the trait is thus quite a different question. As for that, the object is its own (single-instance) type, so could not be overridden with anything as such. If, however, the object extends, say, another trait, then gets assigned to a field typed to that trait, that field could be oeverridden.

Comment: So to make this less abstract, `MyClass` is a DB repo object, e.g. `UserRepo`, `FriendsRepo`. Each has it's own `Queries` object. I want to expose the `Queries` for testing. Currently I'm having to extend each `Repo` object and add a getter, but I'd rather mix in a trait that will expose that Repo's `Queries` object. Your approach doesn't quite work for what I want.

Comment: @jbrown I've added a further edit to my answer that might work for you, given the intent you give in your comment.

Comment: Unfortunately each class has its own set of queries so I can't declare them as part of the trait. The only common thing is that each repo has a Queries object, so I don't think your solution will work for me.

Comment: I thought that is what I proposed (I've edited slightly to try and make it clearer) - or do you mean that each *subclass* of `UserRepo` has its own set of queries?

Comment: No. What I mean is that, e.g. `UserRepo.Queries` has methods `updateStatus`, etc. while `FriendsRepo.Queries` has methods like `addFriend`, etc. Oh actually, you're suggesting I get rid of the `Queries` object and move all those methods out into a trait. That might work...

Comment: Now I think you've got my intent :)   Hope so - gotta go for now!